# How to disable drawing any polygon on Leaflet map

Tags: typescript, dictionary, leaflet, leaflet.draw, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to disable drawing any polygon on map until user selects any radio option displayed in image below. So How can I cancel drawing or disable user to draw anything on map?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
 var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw: false
        });
```

to disable drawing altogether or just disable the polygon with

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            position: 'topleft',
            draw: {
                polygon: false,
            ...
```

To trigger this behavior from your radio buttons, you will have to add some extra logic of course.

Comment: Thanks @Merion, Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, accepting the answer and/or upvoting would be appreciated. If not, please elaborate on your problem and what you tried so far. Then I or others might be able to help.